# Setting up signal masks in a Linux C daemon

Tags: c, linux, daemon

I have written a simple daemon in C, running on Linux. I'm trying to understand how to correctly setup signal masks. I have the following code in my daemon:

```
struct sigaction new_sig_action;
sigset_t new_sig_set;

/* Set signal mask - signals we want to block */
sigemptyset(&new_sig_set);
sigaddset(&new_sig_set, SIGCHLD);  /* ignore child - i.e. we don't need to wait for it */
sigaddset(&new_sig_set, SIGTSTP);  /* ignore Tty stop signals */
sigaddset(&new_sig_set, SIGTTOU);  /* ignore Tty background writes */
sigaddset(&new_sig_set, SIGTTIN);  /* ignore Tty background reads */
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new_sig_set, NULL);   /* Block the above specified signals */

/* Set up a signal handler */
new_sig_action.sa_handler = signal_handler;
sigemptyset(&new_sig_action.sa_mask);
new_sig_action.sa_flags = 0;

/* Signals to handle */
sigaction(SIGHUP, &new_sig_action, NULL);     /* catch hangup signal */
sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_sig_action, NULL);    /* catch term signal */
sigaction(SIGINT, &new_sig_action, NULL);     /* catch interrupt signal */
```

where signal_handler is a defined function. I have a problem stopping the daemon, described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889483/cannot-stop-c-daemon-in-certain-situations-from-php).

I have now tracked the problem to the block mask being different when the daemon is started in different environments (same user, same system). Starting the daemon from the command line yields the following 'ps' output:

```
> ps -C powid -o pid,ppid,command,blocked,caught,ignored
PID  PPID COMMAND                              BLOCKED           CAUGHT      IGNORED
11406     1 ./powid                     0000000000390000 0000000180004003 0000000000000000
```

and when starting the exact same daemon via a PHP script, yields:

```
> ps -C powid -o pid,ppid,command,blocked,caught,ignored                           
PID  PPID COMMAND                             BLOCKED           CAUGHT        IGNORED
11491     1 ./powid                     fffffffe3bfbe207 0000000180004003 00000000010010
```

My question is, why is the blocked mask different. My understanding suggests that the given C code would force the blocked mask to be the same under all conditions?

Comment: Because your PHP interpreter does that. Don't use PHP.

Comment: Not helpful, unfortunately

Comment: I know, PHP is neither a programming language, nor a good environment. Whoever choose it it was deliberately. So, suffer is a part of the bundle.

Comment: What I meant with not helpful is that your comment is opinionated and disconnected from reality, as well as not helping me solve a real problem. Look at the answer below, it has nothing to do with PHP. Because of your bias you are unable to see the real problem.

Comment: Partially. Like below said the PHP interpreter masks stuff. Shell doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [libc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Signal-Mask.html) states:

> Each process has its own signal mask. When you create a new process (see Creating a Process), it inherits its parent’s mask.

So the answer to why is the blocked mask different is because the parents used to have different masks...

Your given C code **adds** some signals to the block list since you use `sigprocmask` with the first parameter set to `SIG_BLOCK`. If you want to overwrite the signal mask, use `SIG_SETMASK`. With that, you should end up with a parent independent signal block mask.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I obviously didn't realize the difference between SIG_BLOCK and SIG_SETMASK, but the documentation cleared it up for me. Thanks for the answer.